# NoMethodError: undefined method `where'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Billings table has office_id(Offices table has many relationship with billings table) and issue_id(Issues table has many relationship with billings table).

I want the billings_ids of all the billings that belong to a office that satisfy condition below. An office can have multiple billing_ids.

Each office should receive a single email with all the billing information about the issues.

I am not sure if I am able to explain or not.

```
namespace :office do
  desc "send reminder emails"
  task send_reminder: :environment do
    Office.all.each do |office|
      office.issues.each do |issue|
        issue.where("issues.amount > 0").joins(:billings).where (issue.billings.last.date < Message.last.date)
      end
      ReminderWorker.perform_async(billing_ids)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: (1) You're calling `where` on `issue` which is an instance of `Issue`, but `where` is a class method, (2) you have a space after the second `where`, (3) where do you expect `billing_ids` to come from?

Comment: I am a bit surprised that you need to run queries inside each loop what makes the whole method way slower than it could be. Can you describe your tables and the model structure? Perhaps this can be optimized to just one db query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this `issue.billings.where("billings.date < ?", Message.last.date)` it will work

Answer (score 1):

`where` work on collection of objects not a single object.